# How to schedule a [WebMethod] in Web Services in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, webmethod

I just got to learn a bit about web services in .net (.asmx and all stuff)

For my project i need to schedule a program which cralwels a set of websites and then update the newly available data to the database every 30 minute.

I have created a `[WebMethod]` for both the crawler code to run and for database updation if available.

But i want that this `[WebMethod]` get automate and runs for every 30 minutes?

Comment: why would you make the crawler method a Web Method?

Comment: And just so you know, asmx is legacy, you should have a look at WCF.

Comment: @BasB :  I need to schedule so that i can get updated database after each 30 mintues or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is not necessary create a WebMethod to do this, you can make in the server side, and for schedule operations, I always use [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Is this Quartz.net can schedule my task if its hosted on a shared hosting environment, IIS  etc?

Comment: @gustavo +1 for quartz.net looks interesting

Comment: @ItsLockedOut yes it can, I usually use in an asp.net website hosted on IIS

Answer (score 0):

I may be incorrect but it looks like you want to schedule a background task using asp.net? I haven't used Quartz.Net but I have done this using a simple example provided by [Jeff Attwood](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/). The following code is from Global.asax.cs and on application startup schedules a recurring job every 60 minutes:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var refreshMinutes = 60;
    AddTask("UpdateInfo", 
            (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(refreshMinutes).TotalSeconds);
}

private void AddTask(string name, int seconds)
{
    OnCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, seconds, null,
        DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
        CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
}

public void CacheItemRemoved(string key, object v, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
{
    if ("UpdateInfo".Equals(key))
    {
        try
        {
            new SearchService().UpdateInfo();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("UpdateInfo threw an exception: {0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    AddTask(key, Convert.ToInt32(v));
}
```

Note Phil Haack has a post on [The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) which provides some useful techniques for making the process more robust.